# How can I access a nested object inside an array to validate it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my schema:

```
  detail: [{
         quantity: Number,

         product:{

            name: String,
            code: Number,
            price: Number
          },
          subtotal: Number

       ]}
```

This is my validations method

```
  const validations = values => {

     const errors = {

       product: {}

       }

  if(!values.detail || 
      !values.detail.length){

   errors.detail = {_error: 'at 
    least one item must be 
        required'}
   }

    else{

 const detailArrayErrors = []

      values.detail.forEach(   
     (item,itemIndex) =>{

       const detailErrors = {}

     if(!item || !item.quantity){
         detailErrors.quantity 
             ='Required'

    detailArrayErrors[itemIndex]=

        detailErrors 
        }

    if(!item || !item.subtotal){

      detailErrors.subtotal 

        = 'required'


   detailArrayErrors[itemIndex]

         = detailErrors
          }

     //How can I access product
      // in validations method

       })

    if(detailArrayErrors.length)

     errors.detail = 
        detailArrayErrors


    }

      return errors;
          }

    export default validations;
```

product is my nested json object inside detail. Detail is an array. I want to validate product. How can I access a nested json object inside an array for validate it?

I've tried using for... of, but it makes not results.

I was searching on web but I couldn't find nothing.

How can I do that?

Anyone who knows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
values.detail.forEach(d=> console.log(d.product));
```

To get array of invalid e.g.:

```
let invalidItems = values.detail.filter(d => !d.product || !d.quantity || 
!d.product.name);
```

To do something on each item in array:

```
this.values.detail.forEach(i => 
{
 let detailErrors = {'quantity': null, product: null};


if (!i.quantity)
  {
    detailErrors.quantity= 'Required'
  }
 if (!i.product)
  {
   detailErrors.product = 'Required'
  }
if (i.product && !i.product.price)
  {
    detailErrors.product = {'price' :'Required'}
  }

});
```

Comment: It should be like this :  const detailArrayErrors= [] 
   values.detail.forEach((item,itemIndex)=>{  const detailErrors = {}      if(!item || !item.product || !item.product.name){       detailErrors.product.name = 'required'                                                                                    
         detailArrayErrors[itemIndex] = detailErrors }  })            right?

Comment: Just showing a way to access the nested object without what to do with it when you get there :)

Comment: Ok. I'll try both ways

Comment: detailsArray.forEach( d => console.log(d.product)). There I'm accessing nested object.   How can I access e.g to price?, price is inside nested object "product." And product is inside an array called "detail".  The better way to access price is it: values.detail.forEach((item,itemIndex) =>   console.log(item.product.price)  )                 right?

Comment: I've edited to show accessing to check if product name is also empty.

Comment: When using map e.g if I want to do something e.g in product's name should be like this: this.values.detail.map( i =>{let detailErrors = {};   if(!i.product.name){detailErrors.product.name = 'required' }});   is it OK using this way?

Comment: In fact just use forEach instead of map (map more for modifying values in original array. Have edited answer. You'll need to provide a value for 'product' if you want to set product.name in detailErrors. Might need to experiment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207602/discussion-between-francisco-arias-and-j-p).

Comment: I'm short of time for a while

Comment: And how can I provide a value for 'product' in code?

Comment: See edited answer. let detailErrors = {'quantity': null, product: null}; then detailErrors.product = {'price' :'Required'}